# NSDateFormatter subtracting a day when removing time

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to remove time from date using NSDateFormatter. This is the code:

```
func dateWithOutTime( datDate: NSDate?) -> NSDate {

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(datDate!)
    let dateFromString = formatter.dateFromString(stringDate)

return dateFromString!
}
```

If i send in ex 04-01-2016 12:00:00, the return is 03-01-2016 23:00:00
I have tried changing the dateFormat, but it still keeps to subtracting a day from the date... Why? Please Help :)

Comment: Use date formatter to display your local time or descriptionWithLocale to know the time at your timezone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28405039/2303865

Comment: Btw you should use noon instead of midnight for "don't care time" date calculations

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-227/

Comment: if you really need the first time of the day you need to use NSCalendar method startOfDayForDate

Comment: Why do you declare the function parameter as optional since you're going to unwrap the optional forced anyway?

Comment: The result is absolutely correct but you are checking it the wrong way.

Comment: I didn't quite understand descriptionWithLocale..
Im fetching records from CoreData and want to get records between two dates ignoring the time, so the date must be in NSDate-format, not string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27369380/2303865

Comment: Again don't use midnight use noon using the method dateBySettingHour to 12pm http://stackoverflow.com/a/30816316/2303865

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `startOfDayForDate` of `NSCalendar`

Swift 2:

```
func dateWithOutTime( datDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(datDate)
}
```

Swift 3+:

```
func dateWithOutTime(datDate: Date) -> Date {
    return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: datDate)
}
```

---

or to adjust the time zone to UTC/GMT

Swift 2:

```
func dateWithOutTime( datDate: NSDate) -> NSDate {
  let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
  calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
  return calendar.startOfDayForDate(datDate)
}
```

Swift 3+:

```
func dateWithOutTime(datDate: Date) -> Date {
  var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
  calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
  return calendar.startOfDay(for: datDate)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was much smoother than using the formatter...
But it still returns one day less than the date, and time set to 23:00:00

Comment: Your time zone is probably UTC +1 so actually the time is correct. If you really need UTC time set the time zone of the calendar. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! You are correct about me being +1 from UTC. With your updated answer everything shows up correct.

Comment: @VegarFlo don't use startOfDayForDate it might not return 12am

Comment: @VegarFlo no need to use GMT time

Comment: But you also said in your comment to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

(a) This can be done without using `NSDateFormatter`. (b) Calling `print(aDate)` will give you the UTC time, not in your local time. After losing too many brain cells trying to mentally convert back and forth, I decided to make an extension to `NSDate` to print it in my local timezone.

```
// NSDateFormatter is expensive to create. Create it once and reuse
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"

extension NSDate {
    // This will print the date in the local timezone
    var localTime: String {
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}

func dateWithOutTime(datDate: NSDate?) -> NSDate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: datDate!)
    return calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
}

let datDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: 2016, month: 1, day: 4, hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
let result = dateWithOutTime(datDate)
print(result.localTime)
```

Comment: Thank you! What you say about calling print explains my trouble. Live in Norway and are 1 hour in front of UTC.
Does this mean that on my phone the date would be "correct" and computer shows "wrong"?

Comment: `23:00 UTC = 00:00 CET`, they both represent the same moment in time. `print` always show the UTC so unless you live in the British Isles, it will give you "wrong" output every time.

Comment: You are using date formatter and stating that it can be done without it

Comment: Btw date formatter default it is local time so you don't need to specify it again